# Write regex for extracting info from the string

Tags: java, regex

I have a String provided below:

```
AWSALB=eIFPQSLLQjg+; Expires=Fri, 20 Mar 2020 03:16:01 GMT; Path=/, AWSALBCORS=eIFPQSLLQjg+vW+; Expires=Fri, 20 Mar 2020 03:16:01 GMT; Path=/; SameSite=None; Secure, SilverWebAuth=48199A; expires=Fri, 13-Mar-2020 04:01:01 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
```

I want to capture only the specific info provided below:

```
AWSALB=eIFPQSLLQjg+; AWSALBCORS=eIFPQSLLQjg+vW+; SilverWebAuth=48199A;
```

I have the regex of (\AWSALB=(.*?)\;) but this only captures the first term. I would like to have the other 2 terms as well. How do I write a regex for the purpose?

Comment: What you you tried? Please post your code and indicate what problem you're having with it. See [mcve]

Comment: I have the regex of `(\AWSALB=(.*?)\;)` but this only captures the first term. I would like to have the other 2 terms as well.

Comment: You might want to try this first: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpCookie.html

Comment: What do you mean by the first term *exactly*? You're using a "non-greedy operator" `?`.  That will narrow the `.*` scope to the first shortest length occurrence of text that matches the criteria. By default regex matches only one occurrence. The regex `g` option usually tells it to capture *all* occurrences of the regex match in the line. Not sure how the results for repeated occurrences will be returned, perhaps as multiple elements in an array.

Comment: I would like to capture the string provided later. ie `AWSALB=eIFPQSLLQjg+; AWSALBCORS=eIFPQSLLQjg+vW+; SilverWebAuth=48199A; 
`

Comment: How about `AWSALB=(.*?);.*AWSALBCORS=(.*?);.*SilverWebAuth=(.*?);`?

Comment: Are `'AWSALB'`, `'AWSALBCORS'` and `'SilverWebAuth'` known fixed labels or could they be other strings that share unstated properties that allow them to be identified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would go something like this:

```
String a = "AWSALB=eIFPQSLLQjg+; Expires=Fri, 20 Mar 2020 03:16:01 GMT; "
         + "Path=/, AWSALBCORS=eIFPQSLLQjg+vW+; Expires=Fri, 20 Mar 2020 "
         + "03:16:01 GMT; Path=/; SameSite=None; Secure, SilverWebAuth=48199A; "
         + "expires=Fri, 13-Mar-2020 04:01:01 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly";

String regex = "AWSALB=(.*?);|AWSALBCORS=(.*?);|SilverWebAuth=(.*?);";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);   // the pattern to search for
Matcher m = p.matcher(a);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
while(m.find()) {
    if (!sb.toString().equals("")) {
        sb.append(" ");
    }
    sb.append(m.group(0));
}

System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Output to Console:

```
AWSALB=eIFPQSLLQjg+; AWSALBCORS=eIFPQSLLQjg+vW+; SilverWebAuth=48199A;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an alternation with an optional part for `CORS` and use a negated character class matching any char other than `;` for the value.

Then you could get the whole match using `.group(0)` or get the value only using `.group(1)`

```
(?:AWSALB(?:CORS)?|SilverWebAuth)=([^;]+);
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aZsmhh/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/s678Zq)

For example

```
String regex = "(?:AWSALB(?:CORS)?|SilverWebAuth)=([^;]+);";
String string = "AWSALB=eIFPQSLLQjg+; Expires=Fri, 20 Mar 2020 03:16:01 GMT; Path=/, AWSALBCORS=eIFPQSLLQjg+vW+; Expires=Fri, 20 Mar 2020 03:16:01 GMT; Path=/; SameSite=None; Secure, SilverWebAuth=48199A; expires=Fri, 13-Mar-2020 04:01:01 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly\n";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Output

```
AWSALB=eIFPQSLLQjg+;
eIFPQSLLQjg+

AWSALBCORS=eIFPQSLLQjg+vW+;
eIFPQSLLQjg+vW+

SilverWebAuth=48199A;
48199A
```

Comment: I accepted the earlier answer, but this is very helpful too.